# Auto not working when struct definition missing

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, auto

I am a little confused that **auto** does not work in *gcc* when there is a struct definition missing. E.g.:

```
0  struct foo;
1  typedef struct foo foo;
2  int test(foo* pFoo);
3  foo* pEvent = nullptr;
4  const auto var = test(pEvent);
```

Where on line 4 the compiler complains that it cannot determine what *var* is. Since test is declared I thought, that it should be a piece of cake. Am I missing something or is this a bug in the gcc implementation?

EDIT:

Sorry, my bad. The toolchain was using the ancient/buggy gcc 4.4. Forcing it to use 4.6 it works like a charm.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=gnu++0x` or `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: In C++ you don't need line 1. 'struct foo;' is enough.

Comment: @Asaf I know, it's just similar to the C header I use.

Answer (score 2):

[It compiles.](http://ideone.com/lW0ZJ)